# JComponent height before painting

Tags: java, swing, components, jpanel, paint

I have a Jpanel where I add many Components (lets say 100 JButtons).
When I now request the height of the added Components there are all 0.
Here come Code:

```
void AddComponents(){

//add 100 Buttons to my jpanel

for (Component component : jpanel.getComponents()) {

      Rectangle test = component.getBounds();

      DebugTextArea.append("\nx: " + test.x + "- y:" + test.y + 
                          "- height: " + test.height + "- width: " + test.width);
        }

}
```

All values are 0. I know it hase something to do with the fact that the painting of the components will take some time, but how can I get the height becouse I will need the height of the Components to set the VerticalScrollBar to a certain point.

any idea?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: sry I will try to do better next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I will need the height of the Components to set the VerticalScrollBar* - no you don't (assuming that's the scrollbar of a JScrollPane which contains the panel with the buttons

```
  button.scrollRectToVisible(button.getBounds())
```

after the component is realized (aka: shown)

Comment: realiszed / shown is the Problem... I add the Buttons and only 2 lines later (in the same function)  i will request the size... and it responst 0.
(And you are right the JPanel is in a JScrollPane)